# Is there a way to set the length of the Cyclic Extrapolation in the Graph Editor?

Tags: animation, graph-editor

So I am trying to do a running animation for my person and I have set the key frames for beginning and end of the movement for the calf and thigh and then set the high point in the middle. I need to have it be a cycle, but not for the entire animation, only for a certain amount of time when the person then stops. Is there a way to limit the length of the cycle that is made using extrapolation, or is there some way to make that cycle for as long as its needed?

I can provide more info if needed to understand what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cyclic extrapolation is actually driven by an F-Curve modifier. In the Graph Editor, press **N** to expose the Properties panel and then go to the **Modifiers** tab and under **Cycles** click **Restrict Frame Range** and change the **End** value.

[image: Modifier]

Comment: That is a big help but I need to go 1 step further and I'm not sure if it can handle it or not. I need to do those walking cycles multiple times, not in a specific pattern, so not every 100 frames do it again. So would it also be possible to set multiple of those ranges where it animates?

Comment: @Syrenthra For character animation, I believe the proper way to go about this is actually to use the **Dope Sheet**. There, you can easily view and copy object keyframes and have them start and stop wherever you need, at it is a lot cleaner than the Graph Editor. Also, you can save any set of keyframes as an **Action** which can be copied and pasted arbitrarily later.

Comment: I am using the dope sheet also but I was unaware of the Actions you mentioned. I will need to look into those then. I am mostly just unaware of how to take a set of keyframes that make 1 full stride for movement and then repeat them without using the graph editor to copy the animations. I will definitely try the Action stuff as that might be what I need.